# Is there a Stack Exchange site for question about swimming pool installation/care?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've tried, twice, to find the right site for the question I'll quote below. I've been shut down, twice, for being off topic. I tried to find the right Stack Exchange site, and it's getting frustrating.

Is there a site where it is on topic?

Now, the actual question:

[First attempt](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17587/how-fast-is-water-typically-added-to-swimming-pools)

[Second attempt](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/36888/how-fast-is-water-added-to-swimming-pools)

I'm curious how much new water (not just filtered) is typically added to a swimming pool. What replacement rate would that imply for the pool as a whole? (Time to replace the whole volume of the pool). I'm sure it's different for indoor and outdoor pools, as outdoor will have a lot more evaporation.

The immediate reason for this question is that my eyes hurt this morning after swimming two hours yesterday. I'm sure it has to do with impurities in the water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home Improvement was suggested in a different answer, but would be off-topic there. When you're in doubt, the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) is a great resource:

On-topic:

- Questions you would typically ask a home contractor.
- Which tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement task.
- Identifying the source or cause of a problem within your home.
- National building codes (of any country).
- Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances.
- Carpentry and woodworking.

Water replacement rate in a pool doesn't go under any of those categories.

If you look at the [list of Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) it's easier finding sites (assuming any) where it would be on-topic.

All the software, hardware, language, professional* and business sites are automatically eliminated as the question would be off-topic in all of them for obvious reasons.

You can look aside the three sites you already asked on, and the sites in the `Culture/recreation*` category.

That leaves a few sites, all of which the question is off-topic on.

**TL;DR:** The question isn't on-topic on any of the currently existing sites in the Stack exchange network.

<sub>* this category is eliminated because of the current sites in the category. The rest of the categories are eliminated because of the category itself</sub>

Comment: Well, sigh. My take-away here is to take my question outside Stack Exchange.

Comment: If you're going to ask on Stack Exchange, Physics or Math is the way to go. Though it's worth mentioning that [a single google search could answer your question](https://dengarden.com/swimming-pools/Determine-Evaporation-Rate-for-Swimming-Pool). Once you have the evaporation rate, you can easily figure out how much to replace

Comment: Far from clear that evaporation rate is the only relevant factor. You have people getting in and out, presumably wetter than they went in, you have water splashing around, some presumably escaping, and so on.

Comment: I don't see how *"the underlying question"* is about evaporation rates at all. The question is about the total flow in, it explicitly states this! - not a fraction of the flow out!

Comment: @Nij It's the currently only form that actually has a site where it's on-topic. The "how much is typically added" question depends on how much is lost, and depending how much the pool is being used evaporation can be the biggest factor. There are **no SE sites for the entire thing** because it ends up being too broad on the sites where calculations for it are on-topic. There are no SE sites for pool owners/enthusiasts atm. In the current form of the question, it's off-topic throughout the Stack Exchange network, so I suggested a change that at least will help make a part of it on-topic on(1/2)

Comment: There's a difference between "your question is actually this, here's where that would go" and "we don't have a place, but here's where part of it could go".

Comment: (2/2) on at least one Stack exchange site. Besides, calculating every single source for water loss is effectively impossible. There are too many factors that depends on variables for it to be possible to calculate a loss over a given time, as it at least involves the amount of people, temperature and a bunch of random causes depending on what actually happens in the pool

Comment: You're assuming there's anything significant to calculate, when the only variables are the rate flow in and the total volume, and the answer comes from a simple division. This doesn't appear to be a theoretical question, yet you are writing as if it must be.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the original question. Editing the answer

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)

There might be a few pool-diggers there who can answer, or at least might have an idea of the pumps needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was actually interested in public pools. Reading what I wrote, that's not at all clear.

Comment: I don't think it matters.  It's just the same thing, scaled up.

Comment: OK, trying it . . . https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/130948/how-fast-is-water-typically-added-to-swimming-pools

Comment: Also closed now. It always pays to check the off-topic pages *before posting.*